# How Linux detects screen resolution?

Tags: linux, display, resolution, graphics

How does Linux detect screen resolution at startup or on-the-fly ?

I want to force a custom resolution on an embedded Linux target which will have user interface not based on X server.

How does Linux reconfigure system when the resolution detected is not one of the standard resolutions ?

Also if possible, please direct me to some text which explains the graphics initialization mechanism at startup.

TIA.

Comment: Please care to explain the downvote.

Comment: seems like a good question to me.  i found the link to VESA BIOS helpful as i'm trying to resolve my resolution problem.

Answer (score 2):

On an x86-based system, the Linux kernel will use a feature called [VESA BIOS Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions) to set the resolution at boot time.

If you want the console to run at a particular resolution, you would pass `vga=X+0x200` to the kernel at boot-time, where X is the VESA BIOS code for your particular resolution.

#### Say for instance you want 1600x1200 @ 24-bit color:

The ***non-standard*** VESA identifier for this resolution is **0x011F** (**287**).

Linux, on the other hand, identifies this as **0x011F** + **0x0200** = **0x031F** (**799**).

You would add `vga=799` to your boot string to get 1600x1200 with 24-bit color.

This code is not guaranteed to work on all video cards, VESA stopped publishing standard resolution codes a long time ago leaving anything above 1280x1024 non-standard.